# Python Flask Templeta <br> newline doesnt work

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

im using python Flask and got this template

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for ticket in tickets %}
       Ticket: {{ ticket.id }} Subject: {{ ticket.subject }} <br/>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

but `<br>` and `<br/>` doesnt work, the Text `(<br>)` is not displayed and there is no new line.

Anyone an idea?

Thank you

Comment: Are you passing `tickets` to the template?

Comment: yes of course and the tickets are displayed but in one line

Comment: Ahh okay - your question says "the text isn't displayed..." anyway - why not put each of them in `p`s or in an `ul` so you've got some structure there? And check what's being wrapped around in from the parent "content" block...

Comment: if i put each of them in a <p> they are still displayed in the same line.

Comment: So if `<p>Ticket: {{ ticket.id }} Subject: {{ ticket.subject }}</p>` is still not working - have you got CSS forcing them to be inline?

Comment: i use css but its the same result with my css disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got 2 templates one called ticket.html and one called tickets.html i copied tickets.html to ticket.html but then referenced ticket.html in the route of tickets

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div>Ticket: {{ ticket.id }} Subject: {{ ticket.subject }}</div>
```